# Unable to unlink a file linux

Tags: linux, links

I have a link file as below

```
    testlnk -> /home/wemohamm/Desktop/script
```

But I am unable to delete the link.
If I use rm testlnk, I get error

```
rm: cannot remove `testlnk/': Is a directory
```

If I user rmdir testlnk I get error

```
rm: cannot remove `testlnk/': Is a directory
```

When I use rm -rf, it deleted the contents of /home/wemohamm/Desktop/script

Finally unlink command throws this error

```
unlink: cannot unlink `testlnk/': Not a directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that ends with a `/` must be directory. You can't `rm` directory. You can remove the link, but the link is called `testlink`, not `testlink/` (which is the directory you get when you follow the link).

Comment: WOW, you are absolutely right. I was using tab to autocomplete the name which took / while using rm command. I just ran rm testlnk and its deleted. Thank you